# ¿Cómo conectar con SQL Server 2017 desde PHP 7?

Tags: php, xampp

Resulta que intento meter los drivers de Microsoft para conectar con SQL Server en PHP y éste no los reconoce:
[image: Php Info]

Y esto está en `php.ini`:

[image: Php.ini]

Ahí están los archivos:

[image: Explorador de archivos]

Comment: Intentaste reiniciar el servidor?

Comment: ¿Podrías compartir la parte superior de un `phpinfo()`? Allí te dirá si has instalado y ejecutado tu servidor en modo de 32 o 64 bits (en el apartado `Architecture`) y también si tienes el modo `Thread safety` activado o no. Dime esos datos ya que sin ellos no podrás saber con certeza qué DLL cargar. Es muy probable que en log de error te estén saltando errores de carga de dichas librerías por no haber elegido la correcta.

Comment: ¿Has podido consultar los datos que te pregunté?

Comment: La arquitectura es x86, Thread safety esta activado